# Symfony 2 - Attempted to call function "apcu_fetch" from namespace "Doctrine\Common\Cache"

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using PHP7.0.8 and the doctrine cache (with APCU) in my symfony project. When I call function from my controllers which use this cache, no problems, It works fine !

But when I create a command file which use a repository which use the doctrine cache, and when I run this command on my shell, I've the error :

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException]
>     Attempted to call function "apcu_fetch" from namespace "Doctrine\Common\Cache".

My configuration :

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle: ~
            metadata_cache_driver: apcu
            query_cache_driver: apcu
            result_cache_driver: apcu
```

The same code works if I run it in a controller :(
I think it's a bug, any idea ?

Comment: I have the same problem on CircleCI, even if it's working well on servers and local env. Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed the very same problem by installing AND enabling php-apcu on my ubuntu machine.

```
sudo apt-get install -y php-apcu
```

DON'T forget to enable the module:

```
sudo phpenmod apcu
```

Double check that php-apcu is loaded in the command line version of your php config. Try to run the following on the command line

```
php -i | grep apcu
```

I got something like that as output:

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini,
apcu
```

which shows me that apcu is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

When you run php from command line, you're actually invoking a php-cli (command line interpreter), not php itself. Php and php-cli are different, they use different config file, and also they can use different extensions. Check you php-cli extensions.